# Launching Spyder Produces Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

From the last few days, my Spyder is not starting, I haven't updated anything in the conda base environment but I can't figure out the problem.
Hope to find a solution.

I am pasting the text of error I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\bolja\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\bolja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 96, in main
from spyder.config.manager import CONF
File "C:\Users\bolja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\config\manager.py", line 351, in 
CONF = ConfigurationManager()
File "C:\Users\bolja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\config\manager.py", line 64, in __init__
self._user_config = MultiUserConfig(
File "C:\Users\bolja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\config\user.py", line 782, in __init__
self._configs_map[name] = config_class(**new_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\bolja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\config\user.py", line 212, in __init__
self._load_from_ini(previous_fpath)
File "C:\Users\bolja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\spyder\config\user.py", line 333, in _load_from_ini
self.read(fpath, encoding='utf-8')
File "C:\Users\bolja\anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 697, in read
self._read(fp, filename)
File "C:\Users\bolja\anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 1017, in _read
for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
File "C:\Users\bolja\anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 53: invalid start byte
```

Python Version: 3.8.5

Spyder Version: 4.2.1

Anaconda Version: 4.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Just over half of the Stacktrace mentions something about configuration, so I will go out on a limb and say your config is corrupted - specifically, some `.ini` file.

Probably `C:\Users\[Your Username]\.spyder-py3\spyder.ini`, tho a `*.ini` search in the spyder config folder shows more `.ini` files. Just check them all for corruptions, or if you don't particularly care about your config, delete them.

Comment: Thank You so much for the help it worked.
Took some time to open but at last, worked.

Comment: If this answer was correct you can upvote it (triangle pointing upwards) and / or accept it (checkmark)